# OpenVPN not default gateway for all traffic

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to make my client forward all traffic through a VPS running OpenVPN. As you can see, it will allow pings to both domains and raw IP addresses, but it will not allow traffic like that made through curl and traceroute doesn't come up with anything. The traffic works correctly when not connected to the VPN.

All information is here: https://pastebin.com/tGspNefn

Thank you.

Working configs thanks to solution below:

**Server:**

```
port <integer>
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert vpnserver.crt
key vpnserver.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh4096.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway autolocal"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

**Client:**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.x.x.x <port number>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert vpnclient.crt
key vpnclient.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: `/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.8.0.5`

why netmask 128.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Thanks DrDinosaur for pointing out http://serverfault.com/questions/312860/why-openvpn-use-network-0-0-0-0-netmask-128-0-0-0-as-default-route

Comment: Next time extract the *relevant* information and include it in the question. Pastebin snippets have a limited lifetime.

Comment: here an update considering ipv4 traffic but also ipv6 https://serverfault.com/questions/408193/how-can-i-configure-openvpn-server-without-push-default-gateway/1053649#1053649

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are two parts into the solution:

**1. Redirect all the traffic into the tunnel**

The easiest solution - use OpenVPN's `--redirect-gateway autolocal` option (or put it in the config file as `redirect-gateway autolocal`.

**2. Handle the traffic on the OpenVPN server**

Now that the tunnel is up all the traffic goes into the tunnel and pops up at the server's end from `tun0` interface.

You need to configure two things to make it work:

***a. Enable packet forwarding***

By default in most distributions the packet forwarding is disabled, hence packets from the tunnel interface never make it to the public interface. You must enable forwarding with:

```
~ # sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Once tested make the change permanent in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Also make sure that `iptables` are not blocking the forwarded traffic:

```
~ # iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

This is good enough for testing - in production you'll want to make the firewall rules a bit more specific, but that's out of scope here.

***b. NAT the outgoing packets from the tunnel***

With forwarding enabled the packets are by default forwarded with their source address unchanged, that is in your case `10.8.0.6` - such packets are either dropped on the ISP gateway or even if they make it to the destination the reply never finds the way back. These private addresses are not routable on the internet.

The solution is to NAT the egress traffic, i.e. replace the private `10.8.0.6` address with the VPN server's public IP. That will ensure that the replies reach the VPN server and there they will get forwarded back into the tunnel.

```
~ # iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**3. Test it**

Now try `ping 8.8.4.4` from your VPN client. You should see a reply. Let us know if not :)

Comment: This works perfectly now. Many thanks for the high quality answer.

Comment: On the client side add add 
pull
to client.conf file, or or add --pull option to command line, so the client would accept configuration pushed by server.
Also if the client runs under Windows Vista or newer disable UAC, otherwise openpn service running on  client will be unable to set routes.

Comment: > b. NAT the outgoing packets from the tunnel
That was helpful to me.

Comment: Really take into account that the FORWARD -j ACCEPT rule makes the Server an open router between all it`s interfaces. It must not be used on production systems. But for an HowTo get it basicly working quickly a very good instruction set.

Comment: Does the `Redirect all the traffic into the tunnel` step in Client config ?

Comment: How about the server is Windows?

Comment: `redirect-gateway autolocal` was exactly what I needed, thanks

Comment: It works, but in server config it must be ```push "redirect-gateway autolocal"```