# How do I route traffic over the a tun0 device (IPSec VPN connection)?

Tags: routing, ipsec, tun

I've set up an IPSec VPN tunnel between my laptop and work. The tunnel gets established, but routing does not.

The relevant part of `ifconfig` is :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:be:d9:6f:a7:eb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.100.10  P-t-P:192.168.100.10  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:94:23:8e:82:0d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.73  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a94:23ff:fe8e:820d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17288561 (17.2 MB)  TX bytes:2462845 (2.4 MB)
```

The relevant part of `route -n` is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

I'm using the IPSec/IKEv2 (strongswan) network manager plugin in Ubuntu to establish the connection.

Let's say I'd like all traffic to get routed over the tun0 device, how do I do that?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look to this answer.. specially the part about the IPTABLES rules... I think it should solve your problem:

[OpenVPN not default gateway for all traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/648118/openvpn-not-default-gateway-for-all-traffic)

Comment: This is just a link. Not an answer.

Comment: Link-only answers are not appreciated here. If you desire to contribute to the site, please post real, helpful content that is relative to the question.

Comment: Its an answer from this very site. I thought it was ok to post answers from other questions..