# Why my OpenVPN Client can not act as the OpenVPN Server's IPMI manager?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I installed the OpenVPN in my Windows server(`43.224.204.19`), and generated the `server.ovpn` and `client.ovpn` files:

This is my `server.ovpn`:

```
local 43.224.204.19

port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

#server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120


comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
verb 3
mute 20

<ca>
....
</ca>

<cert>
....
</cert>

<dh>
....
</dh>
```

this is my `client1.ovpn`:

```
client

proto udp
port 1194
dev tun

remote 43.224.204.19
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun

comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20

<ca>
...
</ca>

<cert>
...
</cert>

<key>
....
</key>
```

in my Windows Server I use OpenVPN GUI connected the server.

and in my Client Windows Server(`45.117.40.20`), I installed OpenVPN GUI too, copied the `client.ovpn` to the OpenVPN config direcotory and connected to the remote server(the `43.224.204.19`).

the client logs:

```
...
Sun Sep 02 23:08:03 2018 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.5
Sun Sep 02 23:08:03 2018 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Sun Sep 02 23:08:03 2018 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Sun Sep 02 23:08:03 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sun Sep 02 23:08:03 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Sun Sep 02 23:08:03 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1535900883,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.0.6,43.224.204.19,1194,,
```

you see it connect succeed.

but, I have an question.

in the Windows Server(`43.224.204.19`) I can input the IPMI address for access it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

but in the Client Server(`45.117.40.20`) I input the IPMI address to the browser I can not access. (`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).

You know the Client have connected to the OpenVPN server, but why the Client can not access the OpenVPN server's intranet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenVPN not default gateway for all traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/648118/openvpn-not-default-gateway-for-all-traffic)

Comment: You haven't sent the OpenVPN client a route for 172.18.1.44.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How to set it?