# Connected OpenVPN Client to AWS VPC but can't access internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, amazon-vpc

So I followed this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html

And I was able to set up a client VPN endpoint, I am able to see the connection as "active" in the console when I activate OpenVPN on my computer. So I know the tunnel is working. However I can't connect to the internet, I even tried adding the internet to my route table (`0.0.0.0/0`).

This is my client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ***.***.prod.clientvpn.us-east-2.amazonaws.com 443
remote-random-hostname
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
verb 3
```

I'm running Windows 10, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Follow these steps here, it may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/648118/openvpn-not-default-gateway-for-all-traffic/648689#648689

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make it more precise. When you say "I can't connect to the internet" do you mean from your home PC while the Client VPN is connected, from an EC2 instance inside the VPC, etc? I've done quite a bit with the Client VPN so can probably help if you can be a bit more precise. Initial guess is to make sure you set it up as a split tunnel VPN on the AWS side.

Comment: @Tim hey yes you're right, I was actually able to solve the problem I think by changing `dev tun` to `dev tap`. However the IP address isn't changing, meaning the traffic isn't being directed through the VPN.